# Multiple definitions of "Main"

Tags: c++

In the journey to learning C++ I'm learning through the C++ Manual that's on the actual website. I'm using DevC++ and have hit a problem, not knowing whether its the compiler error or not.

I was going through this code bit by bit typing it in myself, as I feel it's more productive, and adding my own stuff that I've learnt from the examples, then I got to initialising variables. This is the code that is in the C++ manual

```
#include <iostream>

using namespace std;
int main ()
{
    int a=5;     // initial value = 5
    int b(2);    // initial value = 2
    int result;  // initial value undetermined

    a = a + 3;
    result = a - b;
    cout << result;

    return 0;
}
```

This is popping up a compiler error saying "Multiple definitions of "Main""
Now this is on the actual C++ page so I'm guessing it's a compiler error.

Could someone please point me in the right direction as to why this is happening and what is the cause for this error?

Comment: Do you have multiple files in your project where another one contains a main as well? Usually these errors msgs are pretty self explanatory.

Comment: Which C++ manual on which actual site are you talking about?

Comment: If you don't have multiple files in your project, are you perhaps compiling this single file multiple times? (From the command line, `c++ x.cc x.cc -o x` would do that.)

Comment: @hvd dev-c++ is an ide: http://www.bloodshed.net/devcpp.html so I doubt he's linking the same file twice. (And a fairly old one at that, runs gcc 3.4.2)

Comment: This is not a C++ error, the code looks fine. This error is because you are using DevC++ incorrectly. Some how you have managed to include two main functions in your 'project'. Maybe you are still compiling an earlier program you worked on?

Comment: @CrazyCasta I'm familiar with it. If misconfigured, it could still do that. But fair point that it's unlikely.

Answer (score 10, accepted):

Multiple definitions of "main" suggests that you have another definition of main. Perhaps in another .c or .cpp file in your project. You can only have one function with the same name and signature (parameter types). Also, main is very special so you can only have one main function that can be used as the entry point (has either no parameters, one int, or an int and a char**) in your project.

P.S. Technically this is a linker error. It's a subtle difference, but basically it's complaining that the linker can't determine which function should be the entry point, because there's more than one definition with the same name.

Comment: He can find the other main easily by commenting this main and pressing F10 key to step-in the other main

Comment: Thanks everybody, I didnt realise that in dev-cpp that in the project folder, When I tried to compile one page I was working on, the main in another file must have been apart of it too, So as soon as I got rid of the other pages from the project folder, it worked!!

Comment: If you're using CMAKE with the GLOB_RECURSE-pattern, make sure your build folder is outside of the folder that the pattern works on. I happened to include an intermediate "*.c"-file from the cmake-build-folder.

Answer (score 2):

Found I had two file references in my tasks.json file that were causing this error and which took me a long time to figure out.  Hope this helps someone else..... See "HERE*****" below:

```
     "-I/usr/include/glib-2.0",
            "-I/usr/lib/x86_64-linux-gnu/glib-2.0/include",

        //"${file}",           //HERE**********************

            "-lgtk-3",
            "-lgdk-3",
            "-lpangocairo-1.0",
            "-lpango-1.0",
            "-lharfbuzz",
            "-latk-1.0",
            "-lcairo-gobject",
            "-lcairo",
            "-lgdk_pixbuf-2.0",
            "-lgio-2.0",
            "-lgobject-2.0",
            "-lglib-2.0",
        "-o",
        "${fileDirname}/${fileBasenameNoExtension}" //HERE*************

        ],
```

Answer (score 0):

The reason that you get such error is that you may have used main function several times in this oppenning project. it may be in the very file you have shown or other files in the project. so you have to find where the main function is used and delete them. remember that only one main function is needed.

Answer (score -1):

When I practiced CMake, I encountered the same problem. Finally, I found that the source code path set in the cmakelist project was incorrect. As a result, the compiled files included many duplicate files generated during CMake execution. As a result, compilation errors occurred